# Warning when opening Excel document from a file share

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, network-shares

We’re experiencing a strange issue in Excel.

When the user opens an Excel document from an SMB share, they get a warning that the file can contain a virus.

I do the following steps to reproduce it:

- In Windows 10, open Explorer.
- Go to a file share, e.g. `\\fs20.contoso.local\BI\2021\`
- In the folder *2021* double-click on a .xlsx file.
- After that step I noticed that the opening of the file is not instantaneous. There was a noticeable delay before I would see the contents of the Excel file, around seven seconds.
- Then the user get this warning: *PROTECTED VIEW – Be careful - files from the Internet can contain viruses. Unless you need to edit, it's safer to stay in Protected View.*

Can anyone explain what’s happening here? Why would Excel warn about “files from the Internet” when they open a file from an SMB share on their own Active Directory domain?

Comment: The word internet may apply to any source other than the local computer I think. See if anything in this doc can help>>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-protected-view-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653

Comment: I aggree with Moab, "files from the Internet" means files obtained via the Internet. I suggest you add the path (e.g. `\\fs20.contoso.local\BI\2021\`) as Trusted Locations in Excel.